# Is it possible to configure a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer that reads from DataBase which further depends on properties file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a use case where i have a custom PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer which reads properties from Database and have a dependency on DataSource Bean.

Earlier, Datasource bean was getting created using credentials in .java file only. and so things were working fine.

Now, we want to pick those credentials profile based from .properties/.yml file.

But, now it's like a cycle i.e. Spring properties environment needs Datasource and Datasource needs .properties.

Has anybody faced this problem ? Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can restructure your application that way:

1. Read database credentials from the properties file based on profile you define (e.g. dev, int and prod).
2. Use those properties in order to create `Datasource` to access your database.
3. Now, having the access to the database, you can read what you want from the database and put it into `Singleton Spring bean` which you autowire where you want.

Comment: Thanks M.Mas.

I see.. your suggestion is to read the data source properties manually (File IO), rather than using Spring Injection from Spring environment.

Yes, it could solve problem.

But, if there is something in Spring that may help would be better as then datasource properties would come from Spring Environment which also caters if they are not in .properties file and are at some other place e.g. OS environment variables maybe.

Thanks!

Comment: @Jatinder Jindal, No, you will not read connection properties manually. But, spring will read them from your properties file when launching you app.  Now, for the properties located on you database, you need to read them after Datasource bean creation. (Make them in separate bean injectable where you want).